# Dynamically added groovy property is not unique per-instance

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

If I dynamically add a property to a class, each instance of the class is initialized with a reference to the same value (even though the properties are correctly at different addresses, I don't want them to share the same reference value):

Here's an example:

```
class SolarSystem {

    Planets planets = new Planets()

    static main(args) {
        SolarSystem.metaClass.dynamicPlanets = new Planets()

        // Infinite loop
//        SolarSystem.metaClass.getDynamicPlanets = {
//            if (!delegate.dynamicPlanets.initialized) {
//                delegate.dynamicPlanets = new Planets(initialized: true)
//            }
//
//            delegate.dynamicPlanets
//        }

        // No such field: dynamicPlanets for class: my.SolarSystem
//        SolarSystem.metaClass.getDynamicPlanets = {
//            if (!delegate.@dynamicPlanets.initialized) {
//                delegate.@dynamicPlanets = new Planets(initialized: true)
//            }
//
//            delegate.@dynamicPlanets
//        }

        SolarSystem.metaClass.getUniqueDynamicPlanets = {
            if (!delegate.dynamicPlanets.initialized) {
                delegate.dynamicPlanets = new Planets(initialized: true)
            }

            delegate.dynamicPlanets
        }

//        SolarSystem.metaClass.getDynamicPlanets = {
//            throw new RuntimeException("direct access not allowed")
//        }

        def solarSystem1 = new SolarSystem()
        println "a ${solarSystem1.planets}"
        println "b ${solarSystem1.dynamicPlanets}"
        println "c ${solarSystem1.uniqueDynamicPlanets}"
        println "d ${solarSystem1.dynamicPlanets}"

        println ''

        def solarSystem2= new SolarSystem()
        println "a ${solarSystem2.planets}"
        println "b ${solarSystem2.dynamicPlanets}"
        println "c ${solarSystem2.uniqueDynamicPlanets}"
        println "d ${solarSystem2.dynamicPlanets}"
    }
}
```

In a separate file:

```
class Planets {
    boolean initialized = false
}
```

When this runs, you see something like this:

```
a my.Planets@4979935d
b my.Planets@66100363
c my.Planets@5e0feb48
d my.Planets@5e0feb48

a my.Planets@671ff436
b my.Planets@66100363
c my.Planets@651dba45
d my.Planets@651dba45
```

Notice how for solarSystem2, the 'normal' member variable **planets** has a different address when the two objects are created.  However, the dynamically added **dynamicPlanets** points to the same object that solarSystem1 pointed to (in this case, at address 66100363).

I can reassign them in my dynamic getter (**getUniqueDynamicPlanets**), and that fixes the problem.

However, I cannot override the **getDynamicPlanets** getter, because I either get an infinite loop, or I cannot get direct access to the dynamically-added property.

Is there a way to directly access the dynamically-added property so I could handle this in the **getDynamicPlanets** getter?  Is there a better strategy for this altogether?  Sorry if I missed it, I've looked a bunch...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but if I do, did you try setting the `getDynamicPlanets` closure to have explicitly 0 parameters, so:

```
SolarSystem.metaClass.getDynamicPlanets = {->  ... }
```

If you don't have the `->` with no args before it, there is an implicit `it` parameter that's assigned and it's not a zero arg method, so doesn't adhere to the javabean getter/setter pattern.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point.  I'll give that a try and see if it changes anything.  Interesting that my getter did get used, regardless.

Comment: Well, unfortunately that didn't change anything, but thanks for the tip!